# Is this a security flaw in LinkedIn or a known behaviour

Tags: web-application

LinkedIn owns a sub-site called LinkedIn Learning.

On September 9th, I took a LinkedIn skill assessment on one course.

[image]

As I have passed, LinkedIn offered me few courses, which you can see in the above image for free for only **24 hours**

Here is where I saw a strange behavior. I went to LinkedIn Learning and browsed for other courses and I saw there are no options to view the course for free for 24 hours. i.e **Only the course suggested by them can be viewed free for 24 hours.**

[image]

I monitored the traffic to find how suggested courses get unlocked for free for 24 hours and not other courses. After spending some time in monitoring the traffic I saw a request like this:

[https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:lyndaCourse:/?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_feedUpdate%3A(V2%26VOYAGER_SINGLE_UPDATE%2Curn%3Ali%3AlyndaCourse%3A379656)](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:lyndaCourse:%3CCOURSE_ID%3E/?updateEntityUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_feedUpdate%3A(V2%26VOYAGER_SINGLE_UPDATE%2Curn%3Ali%3AlyndaCourse%3A379656))

I saw a strange parameter in the url like this: `lyndaCourse:<COURSE_ID>`

So, I thought, why not replace the course id of the free for viewing course with the course id of the locked course?

Fortunately, I was able to get the course id of the locked course by viewing the page source of the code with the parameter name

[image]

When a GET request is made after the replacing unlocked course id with the locked course, it gets unlocked for 24 hours.

[image]

My first thought was it would be an Indirect Object Reference Vulnerability because there are no options to unlock the paid course for free.

Now again **another strange behavior exhibited when analyzing the HTML source **

All the videos where actually meida, i.e just embed with video tags which allowed right click download of the videos.

I directly reported to them with screenshots and proof of concept videos, and I got this response.

[image]

So I thought they took this issue lightly and posted it on LinkedIn post and tagged them.

You can see that I have demonstrated with proof of concept video again in the post.

Here is the link to the post which have also tweeted and tagged them as per the advice of other security researchers to let them know.

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/visweswaran-nagasivam-975a8b167_kirstybonner-bug-jobs-activity-6577243206126268416-6L-X

I again mailed them with the link of the post and got this response.

[image]

For a moment I thought it is **not a bug and a known feature** but other security researchers are telling it is a bug. To prove my point I also wrote an automated program which exploits this bug and downloads all paid courses for free which is required for a month in bulk. And still they are claiming it is not a bug.

So my question is **is this a bug or some known feature or expected behaviour?**

If every course can be downloaded for free, what is the need for paying?

Comment: It does look like a bug,but most probably company knows about it.Did you tell them the impact of abusing this?

Comment: @VipulNair told everything to them everything posted here(Screenshots) were sent as video to them.

Comment: Nothing much you can do then.Write up a full disclosure if you want.Thats all.

Comment: @VipulNair All I wanted to know is whether it is a security bug/ flaw or not like if every course can be downloaded for free what is the need for paying?

Comment: Did LinkedIn not already answer this?  Looks like they said it is a known design behavior.

Comment: After reading what they wrote back.I feel there are things that you havent told us.They said that this is normal feature the courses can be unlocked by anyone.Make sure that unlocked content cannot be seen by anyone by any method other than yours.If you cant then its a valid security bug whatever they say but for the time being i would say you missed something

Comment: security(at)linkedin.com I reported but said it is a known feature.

Comment: No, we are not going to "report it to them". That's not our job.

Comment: I removed the image of the running of the program because your image showed absolutely nothing that added to the question (it didn't even show that it worked).

Comment: @schroeder No sir, I just want to let them know that it might be harfmul. I am not a bug bounty Hunter. I typed bug and that was the only tag showed up...

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM hold on - ***harmful*** to what? You have not defined that.

Comment: @schroeder because the instructors are working difficult and people stealing might spoil the hard work... If Everyone can download the course for free what is the need for payment.

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM but they offer free courses anyway. There is already a level of acceptable "loss".

Comment: Reporting a bug this way isn't a way at all, what you forgot is discrercy. They said: "Thanks for flagging, Visweswaran. We allow our members to unlock free courses for a limited time to discover new content and build the skills they need.", I bet they know their infrastructure design well. So the free courses and paid courses are separated anyway, you think you did it, but what you did was just downloading courses that were "paid", no I say free, for a limited time.

Comment: This story do let me think of another story, once there was a report about an issue about Stackoverflow/stackexchange to "manually identify users"; plain browser data fetching  that was not behind a proxy. Also that question had improper arguments to verify the bug was valid.

Comment: Just a quick note to say: doing this kind of investigation without a contract with the target is kind of a risky decision. Just because somebody leaves the door unlocked doesn’t mean you have a right to open it.

Comment: @Preston I never investigated for bug, i found it accidentally I tried my level best to close the door but I failed.

Comment: When you attend a free course, you put in your CC. If you do the above they may tax you for course usage.

Comment: @Overmind I don't understand, I just watched preview which they gave. I never made any course vidoes public.

Comment: They could just say: look, you used this course for 60 days and it was free for 30 as advertised. You therefore must pay for the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You and LinkedIn are talking about two different things.

1. You found a way to use an unlock function in their code to unlock any course you want
2. LinkedIn knows and is willing to take the risk

You want them to take the "bug" seriously. They want to take the risks seriously.

**Is this a "bug"?** No, a bug is an *undesired* or *unintended* function of the system. They know about this function's effects and have told you that they accept it and have means to limit their risks that you do not know about.

There is nothing wrong with this response.

**Is this a "feature or expected behaviour"?** No, it's an *effect* of their design choices. It does not (necessarily) provide them or their users a benefit and it might not have been designed to have this effect. It's a consequence of their design.

System effects can have negative impacts, positive impacts, or neutral impacts. For LinkedIn, they see this behaviour of the system as a neutral impact.

You are seeing that something bad could happen. They are seeing that the bad is tolerable and not worth the re-engineering of their system to change it.

Comment: In mail what I am trying to convey to LinkedIn was everyone might steal the course and instructors hard work... If everyone can download everything what is the need for payment. That was my thought , so you are saying LinkedIn doesn't care. So I should leave it?

Comment: No, you've missed my point entirely. They ***do*** care. But only up to a point. It's not a matter of "yes" or "no", "good" or "bad", "fixed" or "broken". It's a ***weakness*** that they have mitigations for.

Comment: @schroeder" _Is this a "bug"? No, a bug is an undesired or unintended function of the system_" To me, it seems at least plausible that that didn't _intend_ things to be exploitable in this way (and therefore probably _is_ a bug), but – as you say in your last paragraph – the potential to exploit it doesn't trouble them enough to either immediately fix things, or suspend the facility while they do fix it.

Comment: Is this a materially different answer to @BubbleHacker 's post?

Comment: Thank you sir for the most brief answer! 100 of my reputation points well spent!

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is is this a bug or some known feature or expected behaviour?

Well, I think unless there is someone here from the LinkedIn development team who can provide additional insights, it seems we will never know.

But, there are somethings we can point out that may indicate that this is not a bug but rather a feature that can be abused.

LinkedIn probably tried to make an easy integration with their learning site, to do this it was needed to use a flag/parameter such as the one you found. Because of the course being available only for 24 hours they probably did not put to much effort into it because well, what can already happen?

If we look at the business logic, the functionality of the parameter does exactly what it is supposed to and there for, this is a feature.

I think you have demonstrated that you can abuse this parameter to download any/all of the courses available on the site. 
If this is indeed important to them, they are now well aware of it and can probably make some easy changes to fix this, but keep in mind this may not be that important to them (LinkedIn is also known to sue anyone trying to use their data so they may feel comfortable worse comes to worse to use the law).

I would write a write up of what you have found, report it, and if you are told it is not an issue of any sort, you can probably publish it (I would recommend against this because of LinkedIn's experience with people using their data).

Comment: How could they sue me, I have told them before making anything public.

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM, I am not a lawyer but by making code accessible or pointing people in the right direction to how to download the courses for free, you are helping in a crime. This is an assumption.

Comment: @VISWESWARAN NAGASIVAM No, you'd made it publicly before it was *fixed*. (assume this was a valid bug to them)

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM Anyone can sue anyone, the question is whether they'd survive summary judgement and eventually win, and whether you're willing to pay a lawyer to fight them.  Also whether you're in a jurisdiction they'd be willing to litigate in, but that's a broader question.